# Confusion about unit tests (googletest) and projects/folder/files

Tags: c++, unit-testing, ide, qt-creator, googletest

It's the first time I want to use unit tests in my c++ project. Hence I've many existing classes for which I will write tests (at least for some of them). Further, the application has of course a `main()` function.

I'm using qt creator with qmake but could also switch to cmake. The project, qt creator and qmake are working nicely.

My confusion is now how do I add unit test? I intent to use googletest. I've already run a test in a new project, testing some dummy `add(int, int)` function, with everything in one file (function, tests and main). How does that work with an existing project (which has it's own `main()`). Do I need to setup a second project and include the headers in the test files? What is a good folder structure for that?

Comment: One simple way is to create a lib, your application will "only" have the `main`, it will call class/function of the lib normally. Then your Test application can also link to your lib and test its components. (For a total of 3 projects: MyLib, MyApp, MyTest).

Comment: It's definitely best if your tests are in a second project. [This project](https://github.com/nholthaus/units) (which I'm the author of) has gtest incorporated through CMake, you can literally copy/paste the CMake files to get off the ground, and see an example of the folder structure.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best approach is to create a **model library** (with all the production code), a **program executable** and a **test executable**. Then you can link all your production code against the program and test executable. The test-files are also stored in the test executable. All my projects have this structure:

```
model.lib (link against both exe)
program.exe
modelTest.exe
```

In the concrete folder on your file system can be stored the test- and production-files. A build tool (like cmake) should separate the files and put the test files into the test executable and the production files into the model-library.

Consider the following example:
I have a folder with the following files:

```
src (folder)
 - main.cpp
 - model.h
 - model.cpp
 - modelTest.cpp
```

A cmake file could look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(TheUltimateProject)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(program main.cpp)
ADD_library(model shared model.cpp model.h)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(modelTest modelTest.cpp)

target_link_libraries(program model)
target_link_libraries(modelTest model)
```

If you use a testing-framework like google test, you also have to link the modelTest executable against gmock and don't forget to add the include folder:

e.g.

```
link_directories($ENV{GMOCK_HOME}/Debug)
include_directories($ENV{GMOCK_HOME}/googlemock/include) 
include_directories($ENV{GMOCK_HOME}/googletest/include)
target_link_libraries(modelTest gmock_main gmock)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have already installed CMake and the Google Test framework in your system.

I hope the following simple example will help to find an appropriate solution.

The example's files structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── converter
├── converterTests
└── Src
    ├── Converter
    │   ├── Headers
    │   │   └── converter.hpp
    │   └── Sources
    │       └── converter.cpp
    ├── main.cpp
    └── Tests
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── gTestsMain.cpp
        ├── Headers
        └── Sources
            └── converterTests.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.11 )

project( converter VERSION 0.1.0 )

set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20 )

set( SOURCE_FILES 
    Src/main.cpp
    Src/Converter/Sources/converter.cpp
)

include_directories( 
    Src/Converter/Headers/
)

add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} )


##########
# GTests
##########

add_subdirectory(Src/Tests)
```

Src/main.cpp

```
#include "converter.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


int main()
{
    std::string start_date{"23102014"};

    std::cout 
        << std::endl
        << "Converting DDmmYYYY to YYmmDD" 
        << std::endl
        << std::endl
        << "Result of converting " 
        << std::quoted(start_date) 
        << " : " 
        << std::quoted(*date::DdMmYyyyDateToYyMmDd(start_date)) 
        << std::endl
        << std::endl;
}
```

Src/Converter/Headers/converter.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <string>


namespace date
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> DdMmYyyyDateToYyMmDd(const std::string& dd_mm_yyyy_date);
}
```

Src/Converter/Sources/converter.cpp

```
#include "converter.hpp"


namespace date
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> DdMmYyyyDateToYyMmDd( const std::string& dd_mm_yyyy_date )
    {
        // e.g. 20102014 to 141020 or DDmmYYYY to YYmmDD

        if ( dd_mm_yyyy_date.size() < std::string("20102014").size() ) 
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        std::string yy_mm_dd_date = dd_mm_yyyy_date.substr(0, 2);

        yy_mm_dd_date.insert(0, dd_mm_yyyy_date.substr(2, 2));

        yy_mm_dd_date.insert(0, dd_mm_yyyy_date.substr(6));

        return std::make_shared<std::string>(yy_mm_dd_date);
    }
}
```

Src/Tests/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.11 )

set( TEST_SOURCE_FILES
    gTestsMain.cpp
    Sources/converterTests.cpp

    ../Converter/Sources/converter.cpp
    ../Converter/Headers/converter.hpp
)

add_executable(converterTests ${TEST_SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(converterTests gtest gmock pthread)
```

Src/Tests/gTestsMain.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
  
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Src/Tests/Sources/converterTests.cpp

```
#include "converter.hpp"

#include <gtest/gtest.h>


TEST(ConverterTestSuite, empty_date)
{
    ASSERT_EQ( date::DdMmYyyyDateToYyMmDd( std::string( "" ) ), nullptr );
}

TEST(ConverterTestSuite, date_convert)
{
    std::string start_date{"30122045"};

    ASSERT_EQ( *date::DdMmYyyyDateToYyMmDd( start_date ), std::string("451230") );
}
```

Execution of `converterTests` will print:

```
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from ConverterTestSuite
[ RUN      ] ConverterTestSuite.empty_date
[       OK ] ConverterTestSuite.empty_date (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ConverterTestSuite.date_convert
[       OK ] ConverterTestSuite.date_convert (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from ConverterTestSuite (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 1 test suite ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```